# wont add tally master mind game python

Tags: python, random, numbers, pygame

```
import random
thenum = random.randint(1000, 9999)
print (thenum)
tally = 1
guessone = int(input("What is your first guess?: "))
strguessone = str(guessone)
strthenum = str(thenum)
if strguessone [0] == strthenum [0]:
    tally + 1
if  strguessone [1] ==  strthenum [1]:
    tally + 1
if strguessone [2] == strthenum [2]:
    tally + 1
if  strguessone [3] ==  strthenum [3]:
    tally + 1

print (tally)
if tally == 5:
    print ("You Win")
```

When I run this code I only get a response of one from the print tally why is that I add the tally within the if statements I know that I should be using loops but I figured this is what i want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the += operator instead of the + operator.

```
import random
thenum = random.randint(1000, 9999)
print (thenum)
tally = 1
guessone = int(input("What is your first guess?: "))
strguessone = str(guessone)
strthenum = str(thenum)
if strguessone [0] == strthenum [0]:
    tally += 1
if  strguessone [1] ==  strthenum [1]:
    tally += 1
if strguessone [2] == strthenum [2]:
    tally += 1
if  strguessone [3] ==  strthenum [3]:
    tally += 1

print (tally)
if tally == 5:
    print ("You Win")
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do -

```
tally + 1
```

It calculates the result of that expression but then just throws away the result, since you did not instruct the Python interpreter to do anything with the result.  If you wanted `tally` to be increased by one, you have to assign the result back to `tally` . Example -

```
tally += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

All that `tally + 1` statement does is calculate the value of the tally plus one. It doesn't save the new value. You would need to do `tally = tally + 1` instead. However, in this case you can just compare the numbers directly instead of turning both values into strings and comparing those strings (which you could do anyway without manually comparing each character one by one):

```
import random
thenum = random.randint(1000, 9999)
print (thenum)
guessone = int(input("What is your first guess?: "))
if thenum == guessone:
    print ("You Win")
```